# How to ajax insert into value from Modal form result?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, html-helper

I am building an Invoice form where the user must select a customer from thousands of records. In order to allow users to search & select, I want to use a modal form to select the desired customer and then insert the customer id & name into the original form. (I believe this method is a work around for the "no-nested-forms" rule.)

**Invoice Form:**

> Customer : [Select Customer Button] - [Display Name after selected] [hidden: customer_id]
>
> Amount: [normal form stuff]

**Modal Form:**

> Search [  ]
>
> [Table of Customers, filter by search] [select this customer button]

I don't think I need to have a [http post] method to capture the Modal Form's selection - instead I just want to use javascript to update the Invoice Form's value for Customer ID (hidden) & Customer Name.

So far I have:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Modal()
{
     return PartialView();
}
public ActionResult SaveInvoice()
{
     return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveInvoice(Invoice invoice)
{
     dataManager.Save(invoice);
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Modal Partial:**

--have not implement search yet - for now trying to get insertion to work from number text box

```
@model Models.Customer
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header"> Select Customer </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="save-customer-id" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Invoice View**

```
@model Models.Invoice
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <button id="CustomerBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="ShowModal()">Select Customer</button>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customerId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id= "customer-id" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="CustomerModal" class="modal">
    <div id="CustomerContainer" class="modal-dialog">
        @Html.Partial("Modal")
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowModal() {
        $('#CustomerModal').modal('show');
    };
</script>
```

Currently the code shows the form and the button opens the modal with form correctly.

Thanks in advance! I've been searching around but haven't seen anything about inserting from the modal back to the "background page". (And I haven't used AJAX much).

Using:

- Visual Studio 2015
- ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework
- Bootstrap (tried using TwitterBootstrapMVC without any luck)

Comment: Consider using an autocomplete control (e.g. [jQueru-ui Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote))

Comment: Looked into it - very cool. Tried to add it via Nuget Package Manager and it looks like they haven't released an update recently so it is incompatible. 'Error Unable to find a version of 'jQuery' that is compatible with 'bootstrap 3.3.7 constraint'

Comment: Looking into it more - turns out jQuery.UI.Combined is maintained. I'm trying to get a simple sample version working and struggling with it. I have over 30k records - will this really be able to handle filtering through that many records?

Comment: Sure it will. You use the options to make an ajax call which returns filtered data (the ID and Name values) based on the text in the input, and then your include a hidden input for the ID and set in the `select` callback. I will see if I can find a link to good example a bit later

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217750/mvc-autocomplete-editorfor-while-using-html-begincollectionitem/39284188#39284188) for an example. You set the `source:` option to make an ajax call to a server method which returns a `JsonResult` (a collection of anonymous properties containing the ID and Name of the objects filtered by the text in your input) and you set the `select:` option to update a hidden input with the selected ID. If you have that many records, you will probably want to set `minLength:` to be 2 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert value of the selected customer from modal to the background form using the bootstrap event 'hidden.bs.modal' or 'hide.bs.modal'.

**DEMO**

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#customerName").val($("#searchCustomer").val());
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <form>
 <label> Customer</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="customerName"> 
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Search Customer</button>
   <br/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </form>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Search Customer</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Customer
          <input type="text" id="searchCustomer" value="Anil Panwar or id here">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Select</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
         
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Love the concept and that I can run the code from stackoverflow. However, when I copy/paste your code into a dummy project, selecting "Select" from the modal doesn't update the main page. Why is that? I surrounded the js script with <script type="text/javascript"> </script>. Adding console.log statements, it appears that the js isn't running when I close the modal. Any ideas? Thanks! (Again, pretty new to js.)

Comment: Got it working! I changed the script to be: $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function () {
               document.getElementById("customerName").value = document.getElementById("searchCustomer").value;
            })